# How to show that the orthogonal complement of this space is empty?

Tags: functional-analysis

This is a question from the back of the book "Functional Analysis, Spectral Theory and Applications" by Einsiedler & Ward. Let the space $ \ell^{2}_c $ the space of all sequences in $ \ell^2 $ with bounded support, with the norm $||.||_2$ in $\ell^2$. The space $V$ is defined as
$$V:=\{ x \in \ell^2_c | \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x_n}{n}=0 \}.$$
I am able to see that this space is closed. It is required now that I show the orthogonal complement of $V$ is empty. The strategy I have tried is to look at arbitrary element $ w $ in the complement of $V$ with support $ \{ 1, 2, ...,m\} $ and use the sequence $ (1,1/2,...,1/m) $ and bound $ ||w||_2 $ to zero. But it has not worked so far. Could anyone give me a hint? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The complement is the complement in $\ell^2_c$, for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)\in\ell_c^2$ is orthogonal to all elements of $V$. Then it is orthogonal to $e_n=(0,0,...,0,n,-(n+1),0,...)$, where the first non-zero component is the $n$-th component.

From $x\cdot e_1=0$ we get that $x_2=x_1/2$.

From $x\cdot e_2=0$ we get that $x_3=2x_2/3=x_1/3$.

From $x\cdot e_3=0$ we get that $x_4=3x_3/4=x_1/4$, and so on.

Therefore, $x=x_1(1,1/2,1/3,1/4,...)$. But this element is $\ell_c^2$ only for $x_1=0$. Therefore, $x=0$.

Hence, the orthogonal complement is $\{0\}$.

Note: The $0$ vector is always in the orthogonal of a subset of vectors. So, the orthogonal is never empty.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Read the question.